# Sort Array List of objects by generic element

Tags: java, sorting, generics, arraylist, comparator

I have a `Vertex` class which has a field 'element' which is a generic type `T`. The `Vertex` class can be seen below:

```
public class Vertex<T>{

private ObjectProperty<T> element;
private BooleanProperty visited;

public Vertex() {
    element = null;
    visited = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
}

public Vertex(T element) {
    this.element = new SimpleObjectProperty<T>(element);
    this.visited = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
}

public Vertex(T element, boolean visited) {
    this.element = new SimpleObjectProperty<T>(element);
    this.visited = new SimpleBooleanProperty(visited);
}

public void setElement(T elem) {
    this.element.set(elem);
}

public T getElement() {
    return this.element.get();
}

public ObjectProperty<T> elementProperty(){
    return this.element;
}

public void setVisited(boolean b) {
    this.visited.set(b);
}

public boolean isVisited() {
    return this.visited.get();
}

public BooleanProperty visitedProperty(){
    return this.visited;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o == this) {
        return true;
    }

    if(!(o instanceof Vertex<?>)) {
        return false;
    }

    Vertex<?> v=  (Vertex<?>) o;

    if(v.getElement() instanceof String) {
        return v.getElement().equals(this.element.get());
    }else {
        return v.getElement() == this.element.get();
    }


}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return element.get().toString();
}

}
```

I have an `ArrayList` of `Vertex<T>` objects that I want to sort by the vertex's element. In my application the type of the vertex element can either be `Integer`, `Double` or a `String`.

I tried using a `Comparator` but I'm not sure how they work, below you can see what I tried to implement:

```
listOfNeighbours.sort(Comparator.comparing(Vertex::getElement));
```

where `listOfNeighbours` is an `ArrayList` of `Vertex<T>` objects. I get an error for `Vertex::getElement` saying that *'The type Vertex does not define getElement(Object) that is applicable here'*

Comment: You tried that and what was the result? How is the `listOfNeighbours` defined?

Comment: I forgot to write that I got an error, which I have now included in the edit.

Comment: How is the `listOfNeighbours` defined?

Comment: ArrayList<Vertex<T>> listOfNeighbours = new ArrayList<Vertex<T>>();

Comment: No, I don't think this is true, because you can't use a generic type there. You have to use a specific type like `Integer`, `Long` or `Object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the signature of `Comparator.comparing` the generic parameter `U`  `extends Comparable<? super U>`

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
```

which means that whatever `getElement` returns must be `Comparable`.

Note: Here type `T` is Vertex and `U` is the type of what `getElement` returns.

You can solve this by making `T` extends `Comparable<? super T>` in Vertex class.

```
class Vertex<T extends Comparable<? super T>>  {...}
```

Comment: So do I do public class Vertex<T extends Comparable<? super T>>{...} ?

Comment: If so I get loads of errors in other parts of my application.

Comment: @Jaman that is probably because `String` is not comparable to `Integer` or `Double`

Comment: Something like this works  `private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void dummy(List<Vertex<T>> listOfNeighbours) {
        listOfNeighbours.sort(Comparator.comparing(Vertex::getElement));
    }`